# SQL-Server-2017: Self join a table using timestamp criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression, sql-server-2017

i have a table named as `events` and looks like this:

```
            timestamp      | intvalue | hostname | attributes
    2019-03-13 14:43:05.437|    257   |  room04  | Success 000
    2019-03-13 14:43:05.317|    257   |  room03  | Success 000
    2019-03-13 14:43:03.450|   2049   |  room05  | Error 108
    2019-03-13 14:43:03.393|     0    |  room05  | TicketNumber=3
    2019-03-13 14:43:02.347|     0    |  room04  | TicketNumber=2
    2019-03-13 14:43:02.257|     0    |  room03  | TicketNumber=1
```

The above is a sample of a table containing thousands of rows like this.
I'll explain in a few words what you see in this table. The `timestamp` column gives the date and time of when each event happened. In the `intvalue` column, `257` means successful entry, `2049` means error and `0` means a ticket made a request. The `hostname` gives the name of the card/ticket reader that reads each ticket and the `attributes` column gives some details like the number of the ticket (1, 2, 3 etc) or the type of error (i.e 108 or 109) and if the event is successful.

In this situation there is a pattern that says, if a ticket requests to enter and it is valid and happened at a time like `14:43:02.257`, then the message of the successful entry will be written in the database (as a new event) in 6 seconds *at most* (that means at 14:49:02.257 maximum) after the ticket was read by the ticket reader.

If the ticket fails to enter, then after a time margin of 100 ms the error message will be written in the database.

So in this example what i want to do is create a table like below

```
        timestamp      | intvalue | hostname |   result    |  ticketnumber
2019-03-13 14:43:05.437|    257   |  room04  | Success 000 | TicketNumber=2
2019-03-13 14:43:05.317|    257   |  room03  | Success 000 | TicketNumber=1
2019-03-13 14:43:03.450|   2049   |  room05  |  Error 108  | TicketNumber=3
```

As you can see the ticket with `TicketNumber=3` is matched with the result `Error 108` because if you look at the initial table, they have a time margin of less than 100ms, the other two tickets are matched 1-to-1 with their respective results, because the time margin is less than 6 seconds (and over than 100ms). You can also notice, that the hostnames can help the matching, the row with the attribute of the `TicketNumber=3` has a `hostname` of `room05`, just like the next row that has the attribute of `Error 108`.

I've been trying to self join this table or join it with a CTE. I've used cross apply and i also have tried methods using `datediff` but i've failed miserably and i'm stuck.
Is there anyone that can help me and show me a correct way of achieving the desired outcome?
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Please post your most successful attempt and the result that you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time lags don't really seem to make a difference, unless somehow a single room could be interleaved with both success and failure messages.  Assuming that two requests do not happen in a row with no intervening event, then you can use `lag()`:

```
select e.*
from (select timestamp, intvalue, hostname, attributes,
             lag(attributes) over (partition by hostname order by timestamp) as ticketnumber
      from event
     ) e
where intvalue > 0
order by timestamp
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! This does a good job. The time lags don't make any difference, indeed. Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

OK...here is the result you asked for based on the data you provided. This is just an example of how to write a self join to get the results in your example. I hope this pushes you in the right direction.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #t
END
CREATE TABLE #t
(
    [timestamp] DATETIME,
    intValue INT,
    hostName VARCHAR(50),
    attributes VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO #t([timestamp], intValue, hostName, attributes)
VALUES  ('2019-03-13 14:43:05.437', 257, 'room04', 'Success 000'),
        ('2019-03-13 14:43:05.317',257, 'room03','Success 000'),
        ('2019-03-13 14:43:03.450',2049, 'room05','Error 108'),
        ('2019-03-13 14:43:03.393',0, 'room05','TicketNumber=3'),
        ('2019-03-13 14:43:02.347',0, 'room04','TicketNumber=2'),
        ('2019-03-13 14:43:02.257',0, 'room03','TicketNumber=1')

SELECT x.[timestamp], x.intValue, x.hostName, x.attributes result, y.attributes 
ticketnumber
FROM (SELECT * FROM #t WHERE intValue > 0) AS x 
INNER JOIN #t y
ON x.hostName = y.hostName AND y.intValue = 0
GROUP BY x.[timestamp], x.intValue, x.hostName, x.attributes, y.attributes
ORDER BY x.[timestamp] DESC
```

I would not try to copy this into your project and use it, this is just an example of how to use the join. I would need way more information about what you want to accomplish before posting a full blown solution as there much much better ways to produce reports for large data sets.
- Bill

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it helps a lot! You know, it leads me to a good spot, but the thing is that i need to use the time criteria that i wrote above. For example i need to match the ticket number with the first result in the database that comes in the time margin of the first 6 seconds maximum, by the time the ticket number was written in the database. And for this case i step on your script and i also select the time difference between the x.timestamp and the y.timestamp. Then i add a where clause that says that the difference between those 2 timestamps must be < 6.

Comment: I surely am now in a better condition than before and i'll progress. I'll mark your answer as correct if I make it to the correct selection. Thank you very much for your time and your support.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using SQL 2017, you can make use of lead/lag.

```
with evt(timestamp,intvalue,hostname,attributes) as 
(

    select cast('2019-03-13 14:43:05.437' as datetime),   257 , 'room04','Success 000' union all
    select cast('2019-03-13 14:43:05.317' as datetime),   257 , 'room03','Success 000' union all
    select cast('2019-03-13 14:43:03.450' as datetime),  2049 , 'room05','Error 108' union all
    select cast('2019-03-13 14:43:03.393' as datetime),    0  , 'room05','TicketNumber=3' union all
    select cast('2019-03-13 14:43:02.347' as datetime),    0  , 'room04','TicketNumber=2' union all
    select cast('2019-03-13 14:43:02.257' as datetime),    0  , 'room03','TicketNumber=1'
    )
select [timestamp], intvalue, hostname, attributes, lag(attributes) over (partition by hostname order by timestamp) ticketnumber, datediff(ss,lag([timestamp]) over (partition by hostname order by timestamp), [timestamp]) lapse
from evt
order by timestamp
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems as a very good idea, i'll check if the results are correct, i will make the modifications, if necessary and i will let you know.